# minio is not able to read from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I'm upgrading from Minio 3.1.13 to 4.0.4 and have encountered an issue with trying to list files from an amazon s3 bucket.

Here is my previously working code:

```
        var bucket = "my-bucket-name";
        var filePrefix = "379c05ee-d204-4dc7-b26b-66ad8f9e68d4/";
        var _mediaClient = new Minio.MinioClient("s3.amazonaws.com", "accessKey",
            "secretKey", "eu-west-2");
        _mediaClient.WithSSL();

        var exists = await _mediaClient.BucketExistsAsync(bucket);

        if (exists)
        {
            IObservable<Item> observable = _mediaClient.ListObjectsAsync(bucket, filePrefix, true);
            var files = await observable.Select(item => item.Key).ToList();

        }
```

As part of the 4.0.4 upgrade I swapped to the newer style:

```
        var bucket = "my-bucket-name";
        var filePrefix = "379c05ee-d204-4dc7-b26b-66ad8f9e68d4/";
        var _mediaClient = new Minio.MinioClient().WithEndpoint("s3.amazonaws.com").WithCredentials("accessKey",
            "secretKey").WithRegion("eu-west-2");
        _mediaClient.WithSSL();

        var exists = await _mediaClient.BucketExistsAsync(bucket);

        if (exists)
        {
            ListObjectsArgs args = new ListObjectsArgs().WithPrefix(filePrefix).WithRecursive(true)
                .WithBucket(bucket).WithListObjectsV1(false);
            IObservable<Item> observable = _mediaClient.ListObjectsAsync(args);
            var files = await observable.Select(item => item.Key).ToList();

        }
```

I get an exception thrown when I iterate through the observable list ( however bucket exist works fine).
I've debugged the code to where the request is made to s3.

In 3.1.13 the url is formatted to this in the createRequest method:

https://my-bucket-name.s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

however in 4.0.4 this conversion isn't happening and the request is sent to:

https://s3.amazonaws.com

Which is causing a failure with a permanent redirect to the correct URL.

How do I get the client to format the URL correctly?

Comment: Hi - what specific SDK are you using here? It looks like it might be our .NET SDK based on the versioning?

Comment: https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet/issues/673 This might be a known issue - if so we're aware of it and are looking into it.